# How to hide a div on Checkout Page but show on other pages using header.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I want to show certain content consisting within a `<div>` within the website header, so within `header.phtml`. I want to show this on all pages, except on the checkout/cart page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing a pure layout XML solution between all the answers here. Comparing URL's (for instance against `Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage')`)  might **give you problems** when something is out of the ordinary in the URL (like a `SID` is being added, a session ID is being added or there are GET parameters in the current URL).

Here's how you can do this in a clean way using layout XML. Add this to your `local.xml` or your custom module's layout XML file.

Default (all pages):

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="headerdiv" template="page/html/headerdiv.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

   <!-- [...] -->

</layout>
```

Now add another section removing the `headerdiv` block on `checkout_onepage`:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <remove name="headerdiv" />
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

You can repeat this for other page handles, for instance the homepage (`<cms_index_index>`) or the `<checkout_onepage_success>`:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <remove name="headerdiv" />
</cms_index_index>
```

You should add a call to `getChildHtml()` in your `header.phtml` at the point you want to have the `<div`> included:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerdiv'); ?>
```

Of course the template `page/html/headerdiv.phtml`, residing in your theme, would contain the actual `<div>` you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can get checkout page url by:

```
$url1=Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage')
```

And current url by:

```
$url2=Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()
```

Now you can compare if these two are same like:

```
if($url1==$url2) { }
```

**EDIT:** Check below code:

```
<?php
$url1=Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage');
$url2=Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if($url1==$url2) { 
?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .class{display:none;}
    </style>
<?php
}
?>
```

.class is the class of your div.

Comment: What does that look like when I add it to the PHTML file?

Comment: you may add some css or js to hide the div in condition

Comment: do I add all 3 lines of code?

Comment: @Collin yes sure.

Comment: can you just write the if/else statement in php for me please with an example <div>?

Comment: @Collin I have edited the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    <?php if(Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage') == Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()) ?>
        <?php //it is the checkout page ?>
                 <style type="text/css">
                .yourDIV{display:initial;}
                </style>   
       <?php else: ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                .yourDIV{display:none;}
                </style>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add bellow code in `header.phtml`

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout'):?>
<?php else:?>
    <div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php if($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <?php echo 'You are in Homepage!';?>    
<?php elseif(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout'):?>
<?php else:?>
    <div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php $routeName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); ?>
<?php if(in_array($routeName, array('checkout', 'cms'))):?>
<?php else:?>
    <div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php $routeName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); ?>
<?php if(($routeName == 'checkout') || $this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<?php else:?>
    <div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is it possible to have multiple if conditions? For example checkout and homepage?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Updated and with multiple if conditions

Comment: Please consider my answer using layout XML as this is the best practice